# Can someone please explain the word "navigate" for me?

Tags: word-usage

I have tried but I didn't catch the exact meaning from the dictionnary

Comment: Can you please, quote the dictionary definition that you are using.  And secondly explain what is unclear.  As the question stands, all we can do is quote the dictionary at you, and that won't help you at all.  I've voted to close, but I can retract that vote if you can explain why the dictionary is unclear.  You will need to write about five times more to explain clearly.